# mysql: level of error-processing (not logging)

Tags: mysql

I am running 2 mysql dbs. one on linux (v5.0.x) and one on windows 7 (v5.1.55).

I have different behaviour in input-errors (e.g. bad foreign-keys or to long inputs).
the linux version ignores it or just has a warning.
the windows one gives me an php exception. thats a problem.

is it a parameter in the ini-file or is the different in the version of mysql without a chance of configuration. I would like to have the more "cooler" linux behaviour.

thanks!
chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it by my own :-)

its with sql-mode in the mysql ini-file.
disalbe strict-mode will make it not that "angry"